# How can i locate an element in my DOM when its class name is dynamic?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, xpath

I am trying to locate and element on my web page, but the element i want to locate has no unique Id's or anything of that matter. I have only a dynamically changing class name.

I tried using Absolute Xpath but its too brittle.

```
<div class="frca889813467244cd88b375adbb9452c2s4" style="left:274.05px;top:141.75px;width:94.5px;height:18.9px;"><div 
    class="frca889813467244cd88b375adbb9452c2s11">6000.00</div></div>
```

From above DOM i want to get the value every time i locate the above element (Here its 6000.00 but might change in other tests).

Comment: Honestly, ask your developer to add a static id to make the code testable.  Testability is a feature!

Comment: As others have suggested, paste (much) more of the page code.

Comment: Code that can't be tested is not production ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest going with absolute XPath, I know you mentioned you have a hard time creating absolute XPath. I guess below note can help

Note:- if you copy XPath from Firefox it will mostly give you absolute XPath whereas chrome on another side will give relative

or the other way is to make an XPath using another stable element in the tree

I hope this workout for yours. if you can share a link or inspect element snapshot showing Full DOM I can help you even better. Thanks :-)

Comment: I have tried using Absolute but it fails in some cases and is successful in some. :-|

Comment: Can you please share where it is failing so that I can help better